# How to unpivot result in query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I am using MS SQL 2005.

This is the query:

```
SELECT allow_r, allow_h, allow_c, sponsorid
FROM Sponsor 
WHERE sponsorid = 2
```

This is the result:

```
allow_r   allow_h     allow_c    sponsorid
---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
1          1          0          2
```

I need it to be:

```
allow_r   1    2
allow_h   1    2
```

allow_c should not be in the result as its 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you actually want to [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the data which turns the columns into rows.  You can use the following:

```
select col, value, sponsorid
from sponsor
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (allow_r, allow_h, allow_c)
) unpiv
where sponsorid = 2
  and value <> 0
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d949f/2).

The UNPIVOT function does the same thing as using a UNION ALL query:

```
select 'allow_r' as col, allow_r as value, sponsorid
from sponsor
where sponsorid = 2
  and allow_r <> 0
union all
select 'allow_h' as col, allow_h as value, sponsorid
from sponsor
where sponsorid = 2
  and allow_h <> 0
union all
select 'allow_c' as col, allow_c as value, sponsorid
from sponsor
where sponsorid = 2
  and allow_c <> 0;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d949f/4)

Both queries give a result:

```
|     COL | VALUE | SPONSORID |
-------------------------------
| allow_r |     1 |         2 |
| allow_h |     1 |         2 |
```